# error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: gitlab-ci

I need your help. I get the below signature when running my gitlab CI. I verified the variables keys are accurate. Unsure what i am missing. Please advise

$ aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET

upload failed: ./foo.txt to s3://rhinobucket-1/foo.txt An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the PutObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

deploy to s3:
stage: deploy
image:
name: amazon/aws-cli
entrypoint: [""]
script:
- aws --version
- touch foo.txt
- aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET